Firestore Document creation leads to GrpcConnection Error Nuxt3
I want to use the Firebase/Firestore SDK for my Nuxt3 application. When i want to store a new doc in my firestore db it allways leads to the following Error:

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.11.0): GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x29b0fa74 error. Code: 5 Message: 5 NOT_FOUND:

This is how i store the data:
export const add = async (col: string, document: Object) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const colRef = collection(firestoreDb, col);

  const docRef = await addDoc(colRef, document);

  return docRef;
};

The fully code can be found here: https://github.com/julix14/attraction_stack/commit/a5a9c1110f57ad9c80ea425368efde4411a69c83
Is anybody knowing what this error means, what it causes and how to fix it?
EDIT:
I added loggings to see the firestoreDb instance and the colRef:
    Firestore {
  _authCredentials:
   FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider {
     authProvider:
      Provider {
        name: 'auth-internal',
        container: [ComponentContainer],
        component: null,
        instances: Map(0) {},
        instancesDeferred: Map(0) {},
        instancesOptions: Map(0) {},
        onInitCallbacks: Map(0) {} },
     currentUser: User { uid: null },
     tokenCounter: 0,
     forceRefresh: false,
     auth: null },
  _appCheckCredentials:
   FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider {
     appCheckProvider:
      Provider {
        name: 'app-check-internal',
        container: [ComponentContainer],
        component: null,
        instances: Map(0) {},
        instancesDeferred: Map(0) {},
        instancesOptions: Map(0) {},
        onInitCallbacks: Map(0) {} },
     forceRefresh: false,
     appCheck: null,
     latestAppCheckToken: null },
  _databaseId: DatabaseId { projectId: 'activityapp-419511', database: '(default)' },
  _app:
   FirebaseAppImpl {
     _isDeleted: false,
     _options:
      { apiKey: 'AIzaSyAQVJufWha_adYk879BEpM4BwUl4XggkEc',
        authDomain: 'activityapp-419511.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: undefined,
        projectId: 'activityapp-419511',
        storageBucket: 'activityapp-419511.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '412317674095',
        appId: '1:412317674095:web:6792a01c7499d1ce44fb9a' },
     _config: { name: 'server', automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false },
     _name: 'server',
     _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false,
     _container: ComponentContainer { name: 'server', providers: [Map] } },
  type: 'firestore',
  _persistenceKey: 'server',
  _settings:
   FirestoreSettingsImpl {
     host: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
     ssl: true,
     credentials: undefined,
     ignoreUndefinedProperties: false,
     localCache: undefined,
     cacheSizeBytes: 41943040,
     experimentalForceLongPolling: false,
     experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true,
     experimentalLongPollingOptions: {},
     useFetchStreams: true },
  _settingsFrozen: false,
  _queue:
   <ref *1> AsyncQueueImpl {
     tail: Promise { undefined },
     retryableOps: [],
     _isShuttingDown: false,
     delayedOperations: [],
     failure: null,
     operationInProgress: false,
     skipNonRestrictedTasks: false,
     timerIdsToSkip: [],
     backoff:
      ExponentialBackoff {
        queue: [Circular *1],
        timerId: 'async_queue_retry',
        initialDelayMs: 1000,
        backoffFactor: 1.5,
        maxDelayMs: 60000,
        currentBaseMs: 0,
        timerPromise: null,
        lastAttemptTime: 1714043517590 },
     visibilityHandler: [Function (anonymous)] } }

ColRef:
CollectionReference {
  converter: null,
  _query:
   QueryImpl {
     path: ResourcePath { segments: [Array], offset: 0, len: 1 },
     collectionGroup: null,
     explicitOrderBy: [],
     filters: [],
     limit: null,
     limitType: 'F',
     startAt: null,
     endAt: null,
     memoizedNormalizedOrderBy: null,
     memoizedTarget: null,
     memoizedAggregateTarget: null },
  type: 'collection',
  firestore:
   Firestore {
     _authCredentials:
      FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider {
        authProvider: [Provider],
        currentUser: [User],
        tokenCounter: 0,
        forceRefresh: false,
        auth: null },
     _appCheckCredentials:
      FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider {
        appCheckProvider: [Provider],
        forceRefresh: false,
        appCheck: null,
        latestAppCheckToken: null },
     _databaseId: DatabaseId { projectId: 'activityapp-419511', database: '(default)' },
     _app:
      FirebaseAppImpl {
        _isDeleted: false,
        _options: [Object],
        _config: [Object],
        _name: 'server',
        _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false,
        _container: [ComponentContainer] },
     type: 'firestore',
     _persistenceKey: 'server',
     _settings:
      FirestoreSettingsImpl {
        host: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
        ssl: true,
        credentials: undefined,
        ignoreUndefinedProperties: false,
        localCache: undefined,
        cacheSizeBytes: 41943040,
        experimentalForceLongPolling: false,
        experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true,
        experimentalLongPollingOptions: {},
        useFetchStreams: true },
     _settingsFrozen: false,
     _queue:
      AsyncQueueImpl {
        tail: [Promise],
        retryableOps: [],
        _isShuttingDown: false,
        delayedOperations: [],
        failure: null,
        operationInProgress: false,
        skipNonRestrictedTasks: false,
        timerIdsToSkip: [],
        backoff: [ExponentialBackoff],
        visibilityHandler: [Function (anonymous)] } },
  _path: ResourcePath { segments: [ 'activities' ], offset: 0, len: 1 } }


The error typically indicates that the Firestore SDK is attempting to access a resource that it cannot find. Is col the correct collection? Add console logs before the error occurs to check the values of firestoreDb and colRef to see if either of these is undefined or incorrectly set. As I could in your repo (ref), you already catch any unexpected errors in this other place. I think you should do it for this code as well.

@Christian as far as i understand everything is correctly set. I added the logging of the firestore db and the colRef to the Question

So actually the Code was working, but there was an issue with the datastore in the google cloud wich caused the error. setLogLevel("debug") was the missing puzzle piece to resolve this.
